# Something wrong with mongo (1.4.4) request

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

When I query like this :

```
collection.find({ "position": { $in: [ 1, 2 ] } }).toArray()....
```

I get the right result, when I use `$and` or `$or` , for example:

```
collection.find({ $or: [ { "position": 1 }, { "position": 2 }  ] }).toArray()...
```

I always get the empty result

EDIT: when trying to query in console I get:

```
> db.foo.find({"position":{$in:[1,2]}})
{ "name" : "Jon Doe", "position" : 1, "arrival" : "8:00", "_id" :ObjectId("512e2ed286d19b9e4d000001") }
{ "name" : "Jack Smith", "position" : 2, "arrival" : "10:00", "_id" : ObjectId("512e2ed286d19b9e4d000007") }
```

> db.foo.find( { $or : [{"position":1},{"position":2}]} )

```
  //nothing here
```

From this, I get the impression, my code is OK and the problem is elsewhere...

Comment: You have one too many closing "}" after ""position": 2" in the second option, should be `collection.find({ $or: [ { "position": 1 }, { "position": 2 } ] }).toArray()`

Comment: ok, this was just a mistake while copying to Stack, in fact your proposal does that error

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: That's really old.  `$or` was added in 1.6 so there's your problem.

Comment: maybe you can add the version to the question so when people come across it in the future they will know it won't apply to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use newer version of Mongo. It is supported for **version > 1.6**.

See the [changelog](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/908172564/mongodb-1-6-released).

Answer (score 2):

Query Something like this,

```
> db.foo.find({"x":{$in:[1,2]}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("513046c8ec1e5e38449f1789"), "x" : 1, "y" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5130cdfdf8378ccc2005bcf2"), "x" : 2 }
> 

> db.foo.find( { $or : [{"x":1},{"x":2}]} )
{ "_id" : ObjectId("513046c8ec1e5e38449f1789"), "x" : 1, "y" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5130cdfdf8378ccc2005bcf2"), "x" : 2 }
>
```